# Слить два разных репозитория GIT

Tags: git, github

Есть два репозитория, тестовый и боевой (один проект с небольшими отличиями)

```
git@git:anon/prod.git  
git@git:anon/devel.git
```

Я клонирую `devel` репозиторий, вношу изменения, делаю коммит и отправляю на сервер.

Вопрос: как все мои изменения в devel репозитории применить еще и к prod репозиторию?

Comment: Как-то станно, что у Вас один проект имеет несколько репозиториев, а не веток. Получится слить их в один репозиторий, разбив на ветки `prod` и `devel`? Это даст Вам возможность обновить боевой, просто влив `devel` в `prod` и запушив изменения на сервер.

Comment: Да, вот такая вот прихоть руководства. Есть полностью тестовый сервер, со своим репозиторием. Есть боевой. Изменения нужно вносить на тестовый, после чего руководство оценивает функционал и работоспособность. Если дает добро, дублируем на боевой...

Comment: Над проектом работают и другие разработчики, с которыми у меня к сожалению связи нет. Так вот у них, время коммитов совпадает в prod  и devel. Каким-то образом они и туда и туда изменения вносят

Comment: Это ***ОДИН*** репозиторий. Просто его копии размещены на двух разных серверах, и обновляются они не синхронно. Вам нужно не смерджить репозиторий, вам нужно ремоуты проставить у себя.

Comment: @soon, вы видимо никогда не работали с децентрализованными системами контроля версий. То, что описано - нормальная, абсолютно правильная практика.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, Видимо, не работал. Можете в двух словах объяснить разницу между ДСКВ и раскидыванием копий *одного* репозитория по тестовым и боевым серверам, с последующим обновлением файлов, когда на соответствующей ветке прилетели коммиты? И чем это лучше того, когда у нас есть централизованный сервер, а тестовый и боевой сервера выступают в качестве read-only клиентов?

Comment: @soon, это всё вопрос договоренности о процессе разработки в комманде. Лучше/хуже - это некорректный вопрос, он попросту неприменим здесь. Почему так может быть сделано? Ну например, есть договоренность, что в продакшн попадает только стабильный код(после CI и Code Review), и/или банально после его утверждения старшим разработчиком. Так-же, скажем, может быть договоренность о том, что в продакшене 1 коммит всегда равен 1 реализованному требованию или исправлению, а в репозитории разработки 1 коммит равен просто любому прогрессу в разработке.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ без ссылок на длинные мануалы:

```
git remote add prod git@git:anon/prod.git
git push prod master
```

Comment: Вроде оно, но ведь в таком случае,  весь тестовый функционал отправится в боевой репозиторий. Верно?

Comment: @Django да, но вы же попросили все ваши изменения применить в к живому репозиторию. Сравните оба репозитория и как-то выясните что должно попадать в production - только некоторые коммиты, или все подряд.