# Как совместить два репозитория гитхаба?

Tags: git, github

Я сделал `fork` репозитория гитхаба к себе в гитхаб, затем клонировал на два своих компьютера из своего репозитория. Сделал на обоих компьютерах `git remote` для оригинального репозитория. Затем на одной системе сделал комит и залил его. Потом сделал другие изменения на другой системе, которая ничего, пока не знает о комите с первой. Тут в оригинальном репе вышли новые тесты и их тоже хочется к себе заполучить.
Т.е. два вопроса на самом деле, можно ли соединить два комита, которые стартовали с одинаковой версии. И второй, можно ли к ним присоединить третий комит из оригинального репозитория? Работа во всех трех случаях проводилась в разных файлах.
Не смог ничего нагуглить, так как непонятно, как описать проблему.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674523/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427790/262779

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8